# Sort CSV in Terminal according to timestamps using "Sort"

Tags: bash, sorting, csv

There are multiple answers on the forums on how to sort a csv using Sort command of terminal but none seem to be working for me.
This is the file structure:

```
cowboy,16:36:37,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/animation/anime/resources
pants,14:29:10,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/magazines and e-zines
women,01:40:40,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/literature/publishers
happy,05:02:05,2006-03-02,top/adult/arts/comics/free
hen,21:23:37,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/comics/free
hurts,16:49:59,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/magazines and e-zines
tent,00:45:26,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/magazines and e-zines
toon.com,02:00:44,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/animation/cartoons/members
sim city,18:35:28,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/magazines and e-zines
superheros,12:34:15,2006-03-01,top/adult/arts/comics/comic strips and panels/members
```

I tried `sort --key=3,2 -t,` but it won't work. Can someone help please?

Comment: I assume you want to sort by date and time.  I do not think that sort will work with the data that you have.  The data needs to be reordered and reformatted before sort can use it.  If you swapped over fields 2 and 3, combined them into one field and removed all the : and - characters from them then sort -n -k2 would work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sort by date first, then by time, you can use

```
$ sort -t ',' -k 3,3 -k 2,2 infile
```

`-t` sets the delimiter, `-k` the field to sort by. Notice that you have to use `3,3` to sort by the date field only; just `3` would sort using the third field *and the rest of the line*.

`2,2` is technically not required, `-k 2` would work as well. In general, limiting the sort field to *not* use the rest of the line prevents surprising and unexpected behaviour<sup>1</sup>.

Because the date and timestamp are neatly zero-padded, there is no need to sort numerically.

<sup>1</sup> To quote the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation):

> For the large majority of applications, treating keys spanning more than one field as numeric will not do what you expect.

As always: breaking the rules is okay – if you know them.

Comment: Note that `sort -t, -k3,3 -k2 file` will work too.  There is no reason for `-k2,2`.

Comment: @karakfa That's true, I'll point that out. `3,3` is the crucial part.